# Get values of same key from multiple array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key

I'm trying to separate the "TID" in an array from these multiple arrays but I couldn't find the efficient solution.

I've the following type of arrays in one variable:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tid] => 168
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [target_id] => 14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [target_id] => 15
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [target_id] => 37
        )

)
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [target_id] => 36
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [target_id] => 14
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [target_id] => 15
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [target_id] => 36
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tid] => 168
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tid] => 167
        )

)
```

These values are in one variable and there can be unlimited arrays.

And Expected Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tid] => 168
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [tid] => 168
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tid] => 167
        )

)
```

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: And update your question with one dump from _one variable_ like `print_r($oneVariable)` or `var_dump($oneVariable);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are searching for [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

Here is the syntax

```
array array_column ( array $input , mixed $column_key [, mixed $index_key = null ] )
```

Description

```
array_column — Return the values from a single column in the input array
```

Example :

```
$records = array(
    array(
       tid => 167
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3245,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
         tid => 166
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5342,
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
         tid => 168
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5623,
        'first_name' => 'Peter',
         tid => 169
    )
);

$ids= array_column($records, 'tid');
```

OUTPUT :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 167
    [1] => 166
    [2] => 168
    [3] => 169
)
```

If you have more arrays,

```
$records1 = [ ['tid' => 169]];
$ids1 = array_column($records1, 'tid');
```

then you can do [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php).

```
$ids = array_merge($ids, $ids1);
```

OUTPUT :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 167
    [1] => 166
    [2] => 168
    [3] => 169
    [4] => 169
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr1= array("1"); // first 
$arr2 = array("2") // second array
$new = array();

foreach($arr1 as $key=>$value){
 if($key=="yourkey"){
   $new[]=$value;
 }
}

foreach($arr2 as $ke2=>$valu2){
   if($key2=="yourkey"){
     $new[]=$value2;
   }
 }

 print_r($new);
```

Comment: Consider providing an explanation for your answer